# asp.net - images are not shoing in sent email where the body of email is a web page having graph images

Tags: asp.net, image, charts, sendmail

Does anybody know how to get around to following problem.......
i am trying to get a web request in asp.net for a web page which
dynamically generate line and pie chart as per user and then 
sending that web page as email body. but i could succeed only partially
in it. I checked that sent email but it was not showing those 
graphs i was expecting to be there. i tried all possibilities for 
doing this thing work.
this might be due to those graph images not having any link back 
to those graphs generated dynamically at that instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you embed those graphs in the email itself.

It works by attaching the images as regular mail attachments and setting the image source like:

```
<img src=cid:yourImage/>
```

This codeproject example on [embedding images in email](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16730/Embed-image-in-Email-ASP-NET-C) should guide you through it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your fetching an Image which is required to be logged in for (ie logged in as the user for it to be dynamically generated).

I would suggest if your sending this as a email you first download the image, then do one of a few things

- Attahch it to the email (convert it to a png/jpg) then mime encode it and attach it
- Convert your "report" to a PDF and attach the PDF to the email.
- Host your image internally using a unique url ie /graph/{MY-GUID} but then you'd need to store a lot of static images.

This would send over hard copies of the dynamic images rather than relying on the links being generated.

Comment: hey John Mitchell thanks,you got exactly what my question is :) but it would be more appropriate for me to send that page as is when it was generated, rather than sending graph images as attachment because those images can not reveal more about the topic without the description given in page.

Comment: dnyan86 what about attaching a PDF? Remember not all email clients support HTML or some are off by default in some companies.